# How to use threading in cpp to enable parallel execution of two methods from two differents classes?

Tags: c++, multithreading

So, I've been trying to use std::thread object to enable execution of another class method during method execution of another class. Pseudocode is shown below.

```
class A (init_A_args ){
 A::method1(args_method1) {

   method1 functionality;
   return;  
}

 A::callback_method2(args_method2) {
   method2 functionality; 
   return; 
}
}

class B (init_B_args){
 B::method1(args_B_method1) {
    method1 functionality;
    return; 
}

 B::method2(args_B_method2)
    method2 functionality; 
    return; 
}
```

So what I would like to do is something like following:

```
A::callback_method2(args_method2) {
   init class B; 
   for (condition){
       classB.method2(); // should call this method periodically but in such way that it doesn't
       ...;             // block execution of rest of the for loop
       rest-of-the-for-loop; 
       ...; 
   }
   classB.stop(); 
   return; 
}
```

I'm not sure how to do that, but I'm quite sure I need to use threading. I'm able to instantiate Class B in class A callback method, but however, after calling classB.method2(); for loop stops, and execution continues in `classB.method2()`. So `classB.method2()` blocks for loop in callback method of class A. I would however like to execute `classB.method2()` but continue execution of for loop in `A::callback_method2`. After getting out of scope of `A::callback_method2` class B should be stopped and destroyed. So I would like to elegantly switch between execution of callback method in class A and instantiated class B and it's method2 for example.
I've been trying to use `std::thread` but without luck, I'm probably doing something wrong. So to clarify, `A::callback_method2` should instantiate class B and periodically call `B.method2()` whilst continuing `for` loop execution, so B.method2 would be ran in background, whilst for loop executes normally. I have `main` function but it should only instantiate class A, which then in turn instantiates class B, so I'm not sure how that relates to my problem statement (cause I've mainly seen `thread.join()` and `thread.detach()` stuff in main methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide `std::thread` object with a callable object (something that can be invoked) and the thread object will run the callable object. If you don't want the thread to block execution you should `detach` the thread, so it becomes a daemon thread, meaning it runs in the background not blocking the main thread of execution.
When using this solution you should consider the side effects of the callable running on the thread: if it doesn't affect variables/states outside of its scope you don't need to worry about much, but if it does you need to take care of thread safety: concurrent access to variables has to be looked into.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void method1()
{
    long long j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        j += i;
    }
    cout << "Sum is: " << j << endl;
}

int main()
{
    thread t1(method1);
    t1.detach();
    cout << "Stuff on main thread." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::async()` makes this behavior easier to manage, I think.

Comment: That's true, `std::thread` is the lower-level building block of modern C++ concurrency.

Comment: Detached threads should not be used unless one doesn't care whether they finish. Not a beginner's feature. This particular program may or may not print the sum, 
depending on the phase of the moon.

Comment: Yeah, but what happens is that after creating thread, program function as expected, but upon calling `join()` or `detach()` after callback method is going out of scope, which means my classB gets destroyed I get `terminate called without an active exception` and segfault. I'm calling `join()` or `detach` from `A::callback_method2` before going out of scope.